# Vue Bootstrap loading button

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to make loading button with vue.js, and catch the data with it. For now I have almost everything I need to do it but it's not working properly.
So what I really need to do is, catch data and finish loading when data is synced, and I'm doing it a wrong way right now.

This is my button template:

```
<b-button
      v-ripple.400="'rgba(0, 207, 232, 0.15)'"
      variant="outline-info"
      pill
      @click="synchronization"
    >
      Synchronize <b-spinner
        v-if="syncing"
        small
        class="mr-1"
        label="Small Spinner"
      />
    </b-button>
```

Here is my data:

```
data() {
        return {
            syncing: false,
        }
    },
```

and my methods:

```
synchronization() {
            this.syncing = true;
            this.setTimeout(() => {
                this.syncing = false
            })
        },

        setTimeout(callback) {
            setTimeout(() => {
            callback();
                this.$store.dispatch("GET_ORDERS");
            }, 1000)
        },
```

As you see I have timeout to make loader, but refresh time should be as long as it takes to make a request. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: so you are using timeout function just to show a loader ? 
dose the dispatch calls an external api ?

Comment: Well yes, I need that loader for a reason. Yes it is from my laravel api.

Comment: hummm, you're doing it wrong, user interceptors show the loader on each request and hide on each response try 
Vue.http.interceptors.push({

  request: function (request){
    loader.show();
    return request
  },

  response: function (response) {
    loader.Hide();
    return response;
  }

});

Comment: loader.Hide() is a metaphor put inside what ever logic you need to show/hide